# SQL Server: fill Null Fields from Not Null Column for multiple rows having same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I built following Select query to get below results

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductCode, OrderDetails.Coupon
From Orders, OrderDetails
WHERE Orders.OrderID=OrderDetails.OrderID
```

Results

```
Order ID    Product Code    Coupon
22          A
22          B                XYZ
22          C
23          D                123
24          E
```

I want it to display like this:

```
Order ID    Product Code    Coupon
22          A                XYZ
22          B                XYZ
22          C                XYZ
23          D                123
24          E
```

so that it fills empty coupons from not empty coupon field where order id matches.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you have a situation where multiple rows for the same `Order ID` already have `Coupon` values, and for them to differ? If so, what rule(s) should be used to select an appropriate one to fill the `NULL` values?

Comment: What is your JOIN condition between `OrderDetails` and `Orders`? `OrderID` in both tables I guess?

Comment: No Order ID is always unique and coupon will not differ per Order ID.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. OrderID is the key in both tables.

Comment: It seems that your data model is wrong then - `Coupon` ought to be a column on `Orders`, not `OrderDetails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
t1.OrderID,
t1.ProductCode,
MAX(ISNULL(t2.Coupon,'')) as CouponCode,
t1.CustomerName
--Here you have select list by using alias 't' 
--don't forget it to add in group by clause
FROM
(
    select  O.OrderID,OD.ProductCode,OD.CouponCode as Coupon,C.CustomerName
    --Here add the list of columns
    from Orders O
    inner join OrderDetails OD on O.OrderID=OD.OrderID
    Inner join customers C on O.CustomerID=C.CustomerID
)t1
INNER JOIN (
                select  O.OrderID
                from Orders O
                inner join OrderDetails OD on O.OrderID=OD.OrderID
                Inner join customers C on O.CustomerID=C.CustomerID
            )t2 ON
            CAST(t1.OrderID AS VARCHAR)=
            CAST(t2.OrderID AS VARCHAR)
GROUP BY t1.OrderID,
t1.ProductCode,
t1.CustomerName
--Add the extra fields.
order by t1.OrderID
```

**[SQL Fiddle with Your Data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a860e/1)**

Comment: SQL Fiddle example looks good but it fetch results from only one table in my case I have basically three tables Orders, OrderDetails, Customers and their relation is Orders.OrderID=OrderDetails.OrderID AND Orders.SalesRep_CustomerID=Customers.SalesRep_CustomerID
where as the error on above query says Incorrect syntax near 't1'

Comment: it says Invalid column name 'Coupon'.

Comment: @AZee I don't why you getting an error. Can you please paste exact Error?

Comment: actually the field name is CouponCode i changed it from coupon to CouponCode which i believe should not affect it. This is my version of your query http://pastebin.com/3F2wKxTT
The error says: Your SQL is invalid: Invalid column name 'CouponCode'.

Comment: really?? Can you please see the query on above url it has updated field name

Comment: @AZee now check the Updated Query

Comment: it executes without error but is not populating coupon field at all

Comment: @AZee Just give some dummy data for Table **`Orders`** and **`OrderDetails`**

Comment: if you see this query it works just fine http://pastebin.com/ez9cxjs0 but im not getting how to add more fields to it from other tables for example Total_Payment_Received from Orders table while OrderID is the relation among Orders and OrderDetails

Comment: @AZee Basically **[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)** is just to check syntax error. But i am asking you to give tables with some dummy data to prove that my Query will give the Desire output.

Comment: Yeah please download data from here Orders: http://sharesend.com/6l04fbif OrderDetails: http://sharesend.com/nrjqiydk

Comment: @AZee How are you joining **`Order`** and **`OrderDetails`** Table on which Columns.

Comment: by OrderID its present in both tables

Comment: In **[OrderDetails](http://sharesend.com/nrjqiydk)** there is no **`OrderId`** Also no Coupon code is Provided for following ProductCode **KC_DRINK_TASTY_CASE,
KC_HAT_BK_WE,
KC_SHIRT_HIJ_MN_L,
KC_SHIRT_NOW_MN_M,
KC_SHIRT_SIB_WN_S,
KC_SHIRT_TPFA_BE_MN_L,
KC_SHIRT_TPFA_BE_MN_M,
KC_TANK_PK_BK_WN_S**

Comment: Orders http://sharesend.com/pel2hxyb OrderDetails http://sharesend.com/xshpzjyq Customers http://sharesend.com/phs7keio

I want to fetch OrderID ProductCode CouponCode CustomerName the relations keys are OrderID and CustomerID

Comment: Yeah not all products will have coupon code. I just want it to add missing coupon code if it exists in some other row of same id

Comment: if you run this query it works fine in case of CouponCode http://pastebin.com/ez9cxjs0 but i am not getting how to fetch CustomerName from customer table in this query

Comment: The data in the Provided excel are not valid as OrderId is repeated in OrderDetails and Orders Table. So you can't make Join.

Comment: ohh so there is no way to do it if OrderID exists in two tables?

Comment: @AZee orderId in the main Table should i.e Orders should be unique.

Comment: im sorry it seems i am making mistake giving you the data. in main order table the order id is actually unique but its repeated in orderDetails table. i copied both columns from same spreadsheet - my mistake this should work http://sharesend.com/hvkt50l5 sorry

Comment: WOW!! You are the man!! Can you please tell me if I need to fetch more fields from Orders or OrderDetails where should these go I mean in which Select statement.

Comment: No worries man. I figured it out this way: http://pastebin.com/VpUjHkMQ Please let me know if it is also okay because I am getting correct results. Thank you so much for your help!! Greatly Appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Coupon is unique for each OrderID.

```
SELECT o1.OrderID, o2.Coupon
FROM OrderDetails o1 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT OrderID, Coupon FROM OrderDetails WHERE NOT Coupon IS NULL) AS o2 ON o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID
```

Comment: it works great! but when I try selecting fields from other tables it gives error for example

SELECT o1.OrderID, o2.CouponCode, o1.ProductCode, o1.Quantity, o.Total_Payment_Received, c.SalesRep_CustomerID
FROM OrderDetails o1, Orders o, Customers c LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT OrderID, CouponCode FROM OrderDetails WHERE NOT CouponCode IS NULL) AS o2 ON o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID ORDER BY OrderID

relation between Orders & OrderDetails is OrderID AND Orders & Customers is SalesRep_CustomerID

Comment: Take it one step at a time when constructing a complex query. First, add o1.ProductCode, o1.Quantity to the selected columns.

Comment: If it worked, add the following right before the WHERE clause: INNER JOIN Customers c ON o1.OrderID = c.SalesRep_CustomerID

Comment: from your last comment the query looks like this http://pastebin.com/0UeZR6Zk but now it gives ERROR: The multi-part identifier "o1.OrderID" could not be bound.

Comment: "i am sorry but did you mean this pastebin.com/Hku3Nqa9" -> Yes, did not work?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of ugly but does the job:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, od1.ProductCode, COALESCE(od1.Coupon,od2.Coupon)
From
   Orders o
       inner join
   OrderDetails od1
       on
           o.OrderID=od1.OrderID
       left join
   (select OrderID,MAX(Coupon) as Coupon from OrderDetails
           where Coupon is not null group by OrderID) od2
       on
           o.OrderID=od2.OrderID
```

It's using `GROUP BY` and `MAX` to ensure that there's only one row in `od2` for each `OrderID` value, even if multiple rows in `OrderDetails` already have `Coupon` set.